# Некрасивая адресная строка браузера

Tags: php, браузер, строки

Кусочек скрипта

```
<?php
$uid = $_GET['uid'];

if (!isset($uid)) {
    er(15);
}
sec1str($uid);//удаляет теги
settype($uid, 'int'); //привести $uid к числовому виду(?)
// хотя оно и так работает. пусть будет

if ($uid < 1) {
    // чтобы не мучать бд. 
    // будет выведена ошибка и не будет лишнего обращения к бд
    er(15);
}

$q = 'select ..where uid=?';
// работаю с параметризированными запросами.
```

"Проблема" в том что когда в адресной строке вводиться `145ячвап` или `17foo4  -эє   07` или `95+*`, то все работает. Но адресная строка некрасивая.

Хотя мне это даже не фиолетово, а вообще аж никак. К тому же я уверен, что простые пользователи не будут туда ничего вводить.

Если в строке будет `17foo4`, то выведутся данные полученные по 17 uid`у. Я понимаю почему это происходит. Это происходит потому что php сам преобразовывает (приводит) значения переменных к нужному виду.

Если $uid будет `95+*` - будут показаны данные для $uid == 95.

---

Как можно поправить ситуацию? Или пусть будет так как есть? Это же "проблема" высосанная  из пальца.

О том что можно isset и <0 проверить в одном if я знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['uid']) || // если переменная не существует или пуста(==0)
    !is_numeric($_GET['uid']) || // или это не число
    !preg_match('%^\d+$%', $_GET['uid'])) // или число отрицательное/с плавающей точкой
{
  er(15);
}

$uid = (int)$_GET['uid']; // в $uid точно положительное целое число

...
```

Comment: Все! Достаточно было написать, что можно использовать регулярные выражения. У меня в коде они есть, но ночью я  как-то до этого не додумался.

Comment: !is_numeric не работает! в коментах к другому ответу я написал почему.

Comment: @root_x Povierennyy, `is_numeric` работает в этом примере, проверено на локалхосте. Тут данная функция нужна, чтобы в регулярное выражение не ушел массив из $_GET['uid'], если хитрый пользователь его вам отправит через `uid`.

Comment: Должен извинится. Только что проверил у себя - да, is_numeric работает.  А is_int неработает, даже если по гету передается число- наверное потому что проверяет тип переменной (точно не знаю). НО если ПЕРЕД is_int  сделать settype , то даже из неправильной строкой is_int будет работать. Вот потому я подумал что ни is_numeric, ни is_int не работают так как я хочу.

Comment: НО если ПЕРЕД is_int сделать settype , то даже **C** неправильной строкой is_int будет работать.

Comment: @root_x Povierennyy, вы хоть прочитайте про `is_numeric` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php и тогда поймете для чего у меня в if три условия стоит.

Comment: та я понял. НО все равно сделал по своему. Придется ответить так как в коментах код не вставишь. Объясню еще раз что и почему у меня не работало: Я ПЕРЕД is_int is_numeric сделал settype , поэтому некрасивая адр строока была при использовании этих двух функц. А если убрать settype , то is_int выдает false даже если в адр строке число. А is_numeric (без settype перед вызовом) отрабатывает хорошо. Вот поэтому я запутался сией ночию :)

Answer (score 1):

Можешь пользователю сообщать что происходит что то нештатное и ты решил не обрабатывать его запрос.

```
<?php
$uid = $_GET['uid'];

if (!isset($uid) || !is_numeric($uid) || $uid < 1) {
 die('bad parametrs');
}
else { 
// code }
```

Comment: Вы проверяли (тестировали) то что написали? is_int is_numeric - не работают, потому что $uid автоматом приводится к числовому типу. У меня сначала в коде была такая проверка (даже без settype проблема ооставалась). .

Comment: Все раюотает с is_numeric. Я перед строкой is_numeric убрал settype и все стало хорошо.:)

Answer (score 0):

вот как сделал я:

```
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
;//помнить о собакe

if (!isset($uid) || $uid<1 || !preg_match('#^[1-9]+[0-9]*$#', $uid)) {
//В конце регулярнка, потому что она долго выполняется
er(15);
}
//sec1str($uid);
//settype($uid, 'int'); //привести $uid к числовому виду

if (!is_numeric($uid)) {
//эта проверка как-бэ уже ненужна, но вставлю ее в if
echo 'not int';
exit;
}
echo 'int';
exit;
```

---

Comment: Вы сделали не правильно ;) Прежде чем делать присваивание значения переменной `$uid` нужно проверить существует ли вообще `$_GET['uid']`, иначе ваш лог ошибок может быть забит предупреждениями. Я не зря в своем ответе сначала делаю проверки.

Comment: :) Я всегда делаю не правильно, только перед таким пррисваивание ставлю собаку. а сообщения  *Notice: Undefined index: uid* , то есть этот  уровень сообщений можо отключить на сервере.  Сегодня гляну в php.ini - спасибо что напомнили о том что  Notice: тоже пишется в лог.

Comment: Только что проверил: если помнить о собаке то в лог ничего не пишется http://itmages.ru/image/view/4325868/032cb952 поледние 2 строчки после добавления @ перед $uid = $_GET['uid']; Вопрос в том ЗЕЧЕМ я так всегда делаю? Я так делаю  для удобства написания, кода.