# Один "лишний" запрос или все в куче (оптимизация)?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, оптимизация

При любых обращениях к бд в коде проверяется СИСТЕМНЫЙ статус пользователя (не заблокирован ли он на сайте администрацией сайта).

ПЕРВОЕ:

Можно делать один ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ простой запрос и далее решать разлогинить пользователя и вывести сообщение о том что он заблокирован ИЛИ далее продолжить работу (обработку).

---

ВТОРОЕ:

В запросе, например, на вывод инфоПрофиля пользователя вместе с join’ом получать системный статус пользователя и сначала обрабатывать статус, а потом  принимать решение что делать с пользователем и данными полученными в этом запросе.

---

Плюсы первого способа: Легкость реализации, минимизация нагрузки на бд, экономия байтов (байты перерастают в килобайты, кбт в мегабайты, мгб в гигабайты).
Минусы первого способа: Я вижу только один минус - лишний ЗАПРОС, не коннект, а именно запрос к бд.

Плюсы второго способа: не вижу. (или не хочу видеть)
Минусы второго способа: Чуток усложненные запросы к бд, чуток *сложнее обработка статуса* (хотя имеено в обработке статуса нет никакой сложности, сложность скорее состоит в получении этого самого статуса из бд). Лишний трафик.

---

Что значит "усложнение кода" во втором варианте: нужно исправлять, дописывать, переписывать некоторые запросы чтобы вместе с данными получать статус пользователя.

А если следовать первому способу, то пишу всего лишь одну функцию и включаю ОДНУ строчку в функцию проверки состояния кук (включены ли куки) у клиента. Все.

---

Я скорее всего буду реализовывать первый способ. Кто что думает об этом?

Answer (score 1):

1 вариант правильнее.

Представьте что у вас 1000 разных запросов по коду и надо поменять проверку статуса :).

Вариант 1.б: Добавить кэш (memcached/redis/...).

Статус тянуть из кэша, а если нет, проверять в базе и писать в кэш.

При изменении статуса кэш тереть или заполнять правильными данными.

Принцип везде будет похожий:

```
<?php
    //http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php
    //get Status
    // Еще важный момент все хранилища плохо работают с `false` поэтому пишите какуюто строку!
    $status = $cache->get('status_' . $user->id);
    if (!$status) {
        $status = $DBAdapter->getStatusFromDB($user->id);
    }

    if ($status == 'banned') {
        // Kick user out
    }


    //update status on user change:
    $user->save();
    $cache->set('status_' . $user->id, $user->status);
```

Comment: чуток подробнее о кэше. я догадываюсь, но КАК.? можете ссылок натыкать. Хотя вариант с кэшем не очень, потому что нужно всегда точно знать что делать с пользователем. И именно поэтому нужны проверки почти на всех страницах.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/turbocharge-your-website-with-memcached--net-23939

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy Если проверку сделать в начале (подключить файл с проверкой где надо). То всё будет хорошо.

Comment: я на процедурке сижу, НО ваш код (именно вот это) "get('status_' . $user->id);" сделал меня чуть ближе к прнимаю ООП. До меня не доходит принцип ООП (не встречал понятного объяснения, но очень хочу узнать и понять).

Comment: "Если проверку сделать в начале (подключить файл с проверкой где надо)" - ну я же написал куда вставить одну строччку. точнее не одну а пару строк. потому что проверку нужно делать если пользователь уже на сайте, Ну и конечно перед аутентификацией.

Comment: В моэм премере ООП не обязателен поменяйте на функции. Здесь главнее код не повторять чем ООП. А если хочется понять ООП возьмите готовый фрэймворк и посмотрите (Zend/symfony ...).

Comment: " Здесь главнее код не повторять чем ООП." - не очень понял. ну эт не столь важно. Пошел писать код, Я бы уже написал, пока мы тут в коментах тихо беседуем :%)

Comment: По идее сначала надо залогинить пользователя потом проверять.
@root_xPovierennyy Я думаю вам будет полезно посмотреть на mod_rewrite(apache) . Посмотреть на раутеры(https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute, https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute, https://github.com/silexphp/Silex). Что позволит сделать одну точку входа и избежать копирование кода повсюду.

Comment: если у вопрошающего нет вопросов - это плохо. Если после  ответов - появляется еще больше вопросов  - это отлично. Я уже реализовал это и вдобавок влепил туда обновление активности пользователя - для вывода статуса online или Был на сайте... По поводу копирования  кода не совсем понял, НО у меня проверка параметра получаемого по ГЕТу уже вынесена в отдельную функцию

Comment: О такой проверке обсуждение было начато тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527918/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/528142#528142 По поводу ООП - очень интересно! и дело в том что я  начинаю понимать ООП, но прям сецчас наччинать писать используя подхд ООпрограммирования - не хочу потому что тогда не смогу закончить то что сейчас пишу.